# Prove that $\sin A - \sin B + \sin C = 4\sin A/2 \cos B/2 \sin C/2$

Tags: triangles

Prove that $\sin A - \sin B + \sin C = 4\sin A/2 \cos B/2 \sin C/2$ occurs in an $ABC$ triangle.
I don't know how to solve the RHS... Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the Half Angle identities to simplify the right side into terms of A, B, and C. After that, it should be much easier.

Comment: Did trying this help at all? Or do you still need more of a hint? Where did you get stuck if it didn't help?